# SSRS How to Extend a Tablix till the End of the Page?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I am working on a Purchase Order report. now there is a requirement that totals and department name, manager signature etc should come at the bottom of the page. In SSRS it seems to be impossible to attain such a design. Things i have tried

- Put empty rows in dataset but some items have name that comes in two
  or three lines so addition of empty lines is disturbed and total is
  coming on undesired place.
- Manipulated borders and put lines but they
  don't appear on the second.
- Put totals and signature etc in footer
  and show footer only on last page, but pages before the last page
  have that unwanted empty space.
- Tried to set the height of the footer dynamically to set the height to 0 on pages other then the last page but couldn't find anything related.

Please anything i missed or any suggestion to solve the problem would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would would be what Abdul suggested, I'd have thought.  Add a page break after your table, then on the last (blank) page position the text boxes exactly where you want them to go, with formulae summing the required fields over the dataset on which the table is based.  The only drawback of this approach is the end of the table and the totals and footer textboxes will be on different pages.

If this really isn't acceptable (and it's by far the easiest option), then you need to include your totals in the report footer, and set a property for this to have a page break immediately before it.  Not certain if this is possible (and SSRS isn't running on my machine at the moment, so I can't test this).

Comment: I have tried it but still cannot get my required formating